# Stop callback chain and send notification beforeSave method ApostropheCMS

Tags: node.js, apostrophe-cms

I'm trying to prevent the user to save a piece if it doesn't achieve some requirements.

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
    self.beforeSave = function(req, piece, options, callback) {
      let success = true;
      let error = "";
      if (Array.isArray(piece._subevents) && piece._subevents.length) {
        success = self.checkDateAndTimeCompabilitiyWithChildren(piece);
      }
      if (!success) {
        self.apos.notify(req, "Check the compatibility between parent event and subevents", { type: "error" });
        error = "Subevents are not compatible with parent event";
      }
      callback(error);
    };
```

This works but the problem is it shows 2 errors notifications (the default and my custom), 1 because of `callback(error)` and 1 because of `apos.notify`.

Any idea how to stop the item of being saved and only show my notification?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1:**
As Tom pointed out, my code looks like this now:

```
// lib/modules/events/public/js/editor-modal.js
apos.define('events-editor-modal', {
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces-editor-modal',
  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.getErrorMessage = function(err) {
      if (err === 'incompatible') {
        apos.notify('A message suitable for this case.', { type: 'error' });
      } else {
        apos.notify('A generic error message.', { type: 'error' });
      }
    };
  }
});
```

```
// lib/modules/events/index.js
    var superPushAssets = self.pushAssets;
    self.pushAssets = function() {
      superPushAssets();
      self.pushAsset("script", "editor-modal", { when: "user" });
    };
    self.beforeSave = async function(req, piece, options, callback) {
      return callback("incompatible")
    };
```

For testing purposes I'm just returning the error in `beforeSave`. The problem is that an exception is being thrown in the browser console and the modal is not properly rendered again. Here's a screenshot about what I'm talking:
[image]

I'm trying to debug it and understand what's happening but no clue yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your server-side code:

```
    self.beforeSave = function(req, piece, options, callback) {
      let success = true;
      if (Array.isArray(piece._subevents) && piece._subevents.length) {
        success = self.checkDateAndTimeCompabilitiyWithChildren(piece);
      }
      if (!success) {
        return callback('incompatible');
      }
      return callback(null);
    };
```

And on the browser side:

```
// in lib/modules/my-pieces-module/public/js/editor-modal.js
apos.define('my-pieces-module-editor-modal', {
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces-editor-modal',
  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.getErrorMessage = function(err) {
      if (err === 'incompatible') {
        return 'A message suitable for this case.';
      } else {
        return 'A generic error message.';
      }
    };
  }
});
```

If the error reported by the callback is a string, it is passed to the browser. The browser can then recognize that case and handle it specially. `'my-pieces-module-editor-modal'` should be substituted with the name of your pieces module followed by `-editor-modal`.

Comment: Hey Tom, it almost work! I have updated my question

Comment: I have updated my answer to correct a mistake. Should work now!